# Spring ClientHttpRequestInterceptor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the below listed loggingInterceptor in my spring boot app. This interceptor is being called whenever a REST service invoked. I see the first 2 sysout statement being printed immediately and 3rd sysout statement is printed after the REST call is made. Is the REST call made only when getBody() is called? Please can you explain how this works? Thanks.

```
public class LoggingInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor { 
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(" Before Calling Execute in LoggingInterceptor "  + new Date());
        ClientHttpResponse response = execution.execute(request, body);
        System.out.println(" After Calling Execute in LoggingInterceptor "  + new Date());
        InputStream responseStream = response.getBody();
        System.out.println(" After getBody() "  + new Date());
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my two cents on this.

This is due to the fact that ClientHttpRequestInterceptor is an interceptor for request and acts as a proxy.Now,this means it should be pretty much have handle on modifying requests and and the sending the response as needed.

Hence,when the below is executed :

ClientHttpResponse response = execution.execute(request, body);

the response is neither committed nor the request is fired,but is just buffered for modification if any,as is evident from the class :

class InterceptingClientHttpRequest extends AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest {
..
..}

So,when you do below :

InputStream responseStream = response.getBody();

The buffered request fires the request ,gets the response output stream.

Comment: Thanks Ashwini! So if there are multiple interceptors , should only one of them have getBody() call? Should this be in the interceptor with highest precedence?

Comment: So if there are multiple interceptors ,they will get executed based on their order or precedence if you may.Also,getBody is a HttpInputMessage method which is extended by ClientHttpResponse,so having them in different interceptors would not be an issue.Just that,they would be executed in order of their particular interceptor.

Comment: Thanks again. Assume a scenario where I make a call to a REST service AuthenticationService. I have 2 interceptors A and B. A has higher precedence than B. In this scenario , A will get called first and B will get called next. As per you explanation , when response.getBody() is called , the request gets fired. So in this scenario  execution.execute(request, body) in both A and B are called and request is buffered. So will response.getBody in B trigger a call to REST service and will response.getBody in A trigger another call to REST service?